# Regex to capture multiple array index literals inside a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Probably dead simple for someone out there, but I want to build a regex that will search across this string:

```
foo[0][2]
```

and return

```
foo
0
2
```

in the array of matches

So far I have come up with is

```
\([a-z]*)(\[(\d)\])/g
```

which only gives back

```
0: "foo[0]"
1: "foo"
2: "[0]"
3: "0"
```

It's not repeating onto the next literal array in my string, so not hitting the `[2]` part.

I'm no regex ninja, and would appreciate some assistance with arriving at the correct expression I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this pattern: `([a-z]+)|(\[\d\])`

```js
console.log('foo[0][2]'.match(/([a-z]+)|(\[\d\])/g));
```

---

If you don't want the `[]` parts, you can try this:

```js
console.log('foo[0][2]'.match(/([a-z]+)|(\d)/g));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the pattern `([a-z]*)(\[(\d)\])` you could use a while loop to get the first and the third capturing group but note that using `[a-z]*` matches 0+ times and could also match the parts in  `[0][2]` [for example](https://regex101.com/r/RgVrfs/1).

```js
const regex = /([a-z]*)(\[(\d)\])/g;
const str = `foo[0][2]`;
let m;
let result = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches

  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1] !== "") result.push(m[1]);
  if (m[3] !== "") result.push(m[3]);
}
console.log(result);
```

If you want to match that exact format, you could use 2 capturing groups to first match `foo` in group 1 and `[0][2]` in group 2

```
\b([a-z]+)((?:\[\d])+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-z]+` Match 1+ times a char a-z
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:\[\d])+` Repeat 1+ times matching a single digit between `[]` (use `\d+` to match 1 or more)
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE6ojc/1)

If that pattern matches you could get all the digits from group 2 as the overall pattern already matches.

```js
const pattern = /\b([a-z]+)((?:\[\d])+)/;
let parts = "foo[0][2]".match(pattern);
console.log([parts[1], ...parts[2].match(/\d/g)]);
```